# Configure Hybrid Search: getting Access Denied

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, access-denied, hybrid-search

Why is this happening? What I'm trying to do is index content on-prem and ship that to SPO. My content-access account, search service account, all have rights to the on-prem server. They have full read on the web apps and are in the farm admin group. Here's what I'm seeing:

[image: hybrid error 1: azure exception]

I used the onboarding script found here to onboard the search Service App to M365--https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51490&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True

In the ULS logs I saw this:
[image: hybrid error 2: azure exception]

and in Event Viewer I saw this:
[image: hybrid error 3: access denied]

Anyone face anything similar?